# Reducing voltage in a 1966 AM car radio

Tags: voltage

1966 Ford Mustang original 8 track stereo/AM radio that will not change tracks if the voltage is above 12.5 to 13.  The 8 track and AM radio will play as designed without regard to the voltage being put out by the charging system but will not change tracks. My system is putting out 12.5 to 15 volts which is what the car repair manual gives as the proper range.  What can I put in between the car radio and car power wire to get the voltage down to around 12 to 12.5 volts?  I have looked at regulators but confused as to the specifications I need to look for in the regulator.  For example, most regulators I looked at stated the input voltage ranged from 12-40 volts with 12 volts output.  Also, I am confused about what the regulator in regards to amps, volts, etc. What would the regulator do if the voltage dropped to less than 12 volts with the stereo or radio on?  I have taken the radio to a classic car radio repair shop who stated they fixed but it was not fixed.  Any recommendations on what I should buy, to include source if known, would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a detailed answer, however you may wish to pursue having the radio repaired properly. It should not stop working if the voltage is a touch high, and it may stop working altogether soon if something is off.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a regulator such as the [LT1084CP-12#PBF](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1083ffd.pdf). It is a fixed 12V output regulator in a TO-247 package, good for up to 5A (60W out). They're about $13 each.

[image]

The inverse diode across the regulator is probably not necessary, but for a few cents, is not worth eliminating.

[image]

If the voltage drops to less than 13V or so, the output voltage to the radio will also drop. When the car engine is not running, the voltage on the electrical system is normally only a bit over 12V, so you won't likely get more than 11 and change at the radio.

If you have a adjustable bench DC power supply capable of enough current you could change the voltage downward from 12V and verify where it stops working. You could also verify the current draw to ensure that 5A is sufficient.

You **must** have a sufficiently large capacitor of the correct type on the output of this kind of regulator (it's an LDO type) or it *will* be unstable, I suggest a normal (not low impedance) 470uF/25V electrolytic rated at 105°C. I do not suggest a tantalum or ceramic part. A similar part on the input will be okay. They're about 45 cents each.

[image]

I would also suggest a healthy unipolar TVS diode on the input capable of 1500W surges and rated at perhaps 24V. Something like a [1.5KE30A-TP](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1.5KE6.8%28C%29%28A%29-1.5KE550%28C%29%28A%29%28DO-201AE%29.pdf). about 50 cents.

[image]

Be sure to provide a sufficient heatsink.. a 5A load with 3V drop means 15W are going to have to be dissipated without it getting overly toasty, even on a fine summer day with the dash really, really hot. The part has thermal shutdown to save itself, but you should not test it.